# clang/gcc c++, is it possible for the compiler to output a list of all initialized templates in each .cpp?

Tags: c++, templates

I am sick of the slow compile time due to heavy use of templates.

c++11 allow using `extern template` to skip a template initialization in a translation unit: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSLTBW_2.4.0/com.ibm.zos.v2r4.cbclx01/explicit_instantiation.htm

I am thinking of generating an `extern template` list automatically, so most of the inited templates can be initialize in a single `.obj` file once, so in a sense cache these template initializations.

the idea is like:

```
//main.cpp
#include <funfunc.h>

//auto-generated list
extern template void funfunc<class1>();
extern template void funfunc<class2>();
extern template void funfunc<class3>();
//end of auto-generated list

int main(){
  funfunc<class1>();
  funfunc<class2>();
  funfunc<class3>();
}
```

```
//template_init.cpp
#include <funfunc.h>

//auto-generated list
template void funfunc<class1>();
template void funfunc<class2>();
template void funfunc<class3>();
//end of auto-generated list
```

Is this automated process possible?

Comment: it is unclear what you're trying to achieve

Comment: So assuming you explicitly override some of the implicitly generated template code, you would like the compiler to output which template code it **did** create?

Comment: @OrenIshShalom It should just output the "title" not the "body". So should not make a difference. It only depends on the call-site code.

Comment: Pre compiled headers would probably be more effective

Comment: @AlanBirtles Pre compiled headers in gcc/clang only cache the parse result, template initialization happen in another stage.

Comment: Parsing the headers is often a significant proportion of the compile time. For code generation of templates you might have some success with link time optimisation/code generation